# Why can't I pass a value from <li> to a text field?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to create a search-as-you-type field and to pass those values into another text field on click. But when I click on the results nothing happens.

Here's part of the HTML

```
    <!-- Main Input -->
    <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" id="mytext">
    <!-- Show Results -->
    <h4 id="results-text">Showing results for: <b id="search-string">Array</b></h4>
    <ul id="results"></ul>


</div>

</body>

<script>
$(".myLi").click(function(){
$('#mytext').val($(this).text());
});

</script>

<script>
$(function () {
$('#results').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#text');
    text.val();    
});
});
</script>


</html>
```

Part of the PHP is here

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<li value="myLi" class="myLi">My element 1</li>';
```

Comment: No element at `html` has `id` `"text"`? What is expected result of `var text = $('#text');
    text.val();`?

Comment: Have you confirmed the html string from the php is correctly populating in the html page?

Comment: `$html = "<li value='myLi' class='myLi'>My element 1</li>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clicking `li` but `ul`.

hope this snippet will be useful

```
$('#results') .on('click','.myLi',function(){
  $('#text').val($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question, how would I choose what value to pass because at the moment it only passes all the values inside the <li> tag. I want the <li> tag to show for example "Dog Tokyo" then I want to pass only the "Dog" text.